# Hibernate @Valid and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

Before asking here, I googled and search here a lot, find a usefull content, but I could not solve my problem.

I´m studing the use of Spring MVC and Hibernate Validator with i18n support. My problem is related when the form needs to be validated, below is the code I generated.

Bean User

```
@Entity(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}
```

UserController

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doSave(@ModelAttribute("formUsuario") @Valid br.com.rodrigoferra.domain.User user, BindingResult results, Model model) {

        UserValidator userValidator = new UserValidator();

        userValidator.validate(user, results);

        if(results.hasErrors()) {
            return "users/edit";
        }

        user = userService.create(user);

        return "redirect:/users/";

    }
```

UserValidator

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    @Autowired private MessageSource messageSource;

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("controller");

    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return User.class.equals(clazz);
    }

    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        logger.info("Entrou em validate");

    User user = (User) target;

    if (user.getFirstName() == null) {
        errors.rejectValue("firstName", "NotEmpty.user.firstName");
    }

    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "NotEmpty.user.firstName");

    }

}
```

The location where messages.properties is located:
[image]
Finally, the applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames" value="classpath:/resources/i18n/messages, classpath:/resources/i18n/errors" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
        <property name="validationMessageSource">
            <ref bean="messageSource" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="pt_BR" />
    </bean>
```

The error reported when the method is executed:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/simpla-spring-version] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/layouts/simpleLayout.jsp'.] with root cause
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'NotEmpty.user.firstName' for locale 'pt_BR'.
```

messages_pt_BR.properties, same to messages.properties:

```
NotEmpty.user.firstName = Name is required!
```

Well, I´m getting crazy with it, already changed the location, tryed a lot of samples founded over the web and spring forum... I appreciate any help.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: There is an error and it is trying to display the message NotEmpty.user.firstname, but the message.properties does not contain that property

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the messages.properties!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to your messages file is wrong, the content of the resources directory is directly added to the classpath (just like the java directory). More information can be found on the [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) website

So instead of `classpath:/resources/i18n/messages` use `classpath:/i18n/messages` and the same goed for the errors file ofcourse.

Comment: I will test, the message need the NotEmpty as prefix? NotEmpty.user.firstName or just user.firstName?